# Discrete Markov process on finite interval

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, random-walks

Consider an contiguous array of $N$ states, numbered from $1$ to $N$.
At every time step $t$, the process should transition to an adjacent state.

The probability of moving to the right (from state $n\rightarrow n+1$) for every state $n$ is given by $P[n]$. The process thus moves left with probability $1-P[n]$ (from state $n\rightarrow n-1$).

We have that $P[1]=1$; $P[N]=0$; $0<P[n]<1, \forall n\in \{2,...,N-1\}$.

I would like to model the "occupancy" distribution $O$ as a function of $P$ (and vice versa), describing the probability of finding the Markov process in state $n$ at any given time step $t$. Formally:
$$O[n] = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{\#\textrm{times state}\:n\:\textrm{was visited}}{t}}$$
Is there a way to analytically determine the values of $O[n]$ for a given $P[n]$, or conversely find the needed values $P[n]$ to obtain a desired distribution $O[n]$?

Comment: This question is probably better for Math Stack Exchange, but I think you can find everything you need in Chapter 1 of *Essentials of Stochastic Processes* by Durrett (an undergraduate text).  Your question is equivalent to finding the *stationary distribution* which in general reduces to linear algebra.  Your process is a *birth-death chain* and it satisfies the *detailed balance condition*, which makes things simpler and you get a nice recurrence to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't realize there were multiple Math exchange forums. I didn't know what terminology to look for, so that's a good starting point.

Comment: To add onto Nate's comment: in the language of Markov chains, you just need to show that it's *reversible* with respect to a given measure (this is what Nate called "detailed balance conditions").  To answer your question about choosing $P$ to get a desired $O$, you can indeed do this, for instance using the *Metropolis* algorithm (sometimes called Metropolis-Hastings).  Another reference that's specifically entirely about Markov chains is *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres and Wilmer (it's also available on Levin's website).